# Image button changes image

Tags: android, imageview

I have a image button and i want that image button when pressed it changes the text in a textbox and it changes a image to a different image how do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an OnClickListener: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html

When clicked your text can be changed with (something like) text.setText("new text");

I'll find a link in a minute which will help more.

Comment: Thank you, ill look at that link you sent me while you get link

Comment: if you follow this and subsequent tutorials, it will explain everything you need : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SxGYGYBFrOM

Comment: user650309        http://pastebin.com/0drNC19Z i get a error on the info

error = info cannot be resolved

info is the id of my textbox

Comment: Whatever you just posted and deleted looked like the right code. I'm at work now but I'll be able to post code that works later on if you can't find anything  EDIT: You know that you have to make sure the java code has read in the xml with something like:  TextView info = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.info);

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestesetetActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    TextView textview = null;
    ImageButton buttonResume = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        buttonResume = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        buttonResume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textview.setText("test");
                buttonResume.setImageResource(R.drawable.push_pin);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the xml file, you can give the image an onClick attribute, which calls a method in the java class, which calls the xml resource, and passes it the id of the ImageView.

In that java method, you can use

```
((ImageView) view).setImageResource(int id)
```

or

```
setImageDrawable(Drawable d)
```

to change the image.

Likewise, you can identify the TextView you wish to change using, for example,

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById( id )
```

with id being the id of the TextView you wish to find.

You can then use

```
tv.setText(String s)
```

to set the text in this view.

Answer (score 0):

In your OnClickListener, you could use

```
button.setBackgroundResource(YOUR_BUTTON_ID);
```

or

```
button.setImageResource(YOUR_BUTTON_ID);
```