# Android ImageView changes background image

Tags: android

How can i make a ImageView button change the background image?

Like you hit the imageview button and then the background changes to what i set it to

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779249/image-button-changes-image

It looks like you received an answer here.

Comment: i want to change the BACKGROUND image not change a image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got lots of methods for it

```
ImageView i;
    i.setImageBitmap(bm);
    i.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    i.setImageResource(resId);
```

All you need to do is to check documentation and you'll find an answer. No need to post such questions on StackOverFlow. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/pic1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/before_pic" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click Here"
    android:onClick="switchPic" />


/**
  * Called when button is clicked.
  */
 public void switchPic(View view) {
    ImageView after = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic1);
    after.setImageResource(R.drawable.after_pic);
}
```

In XML, assuming the ImageView tag is in your parent view so it would fill the background, set it to your first image, "before_pic". When the Button is clicked it calls the switchPic function.

In the switchPic function, first we create an ImageView object called 'after' and pass it the same ImageView "pic1". Then re-inflate it with the new image "after_pic" with this line of code: `after.setImageResource(R.drawable.after_pic);`

Comment: Try to add an explanation to your answer please.

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.YOUR_DRAWABLE);
```

These are your options for a button.